# lucene query for results within x% of top score

Tags: java, lucene

I have a lucene index that I'm trying to query. Given a query `Q`, I'd like to find all the results that are within, say 10%, of that top score. So if my top result returns 5.0 I'd like to get all the results whose score is greater than 4.5. Is this possible? Currently I'm just doing

```
 IndexSearches.search(Q, 1000);
```

hoping that 1000 is more than enough to contain the cutoff value and then comparing the score to the threshold. This seems like extra work as well as potentially problematic if I need to go back and query again if all the initial 1000 are above the cutoff. Is there an easier way to do this?

All the Collectors I've looked at seem to take a number of results as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the short answer is: Don't do it

Getting the top x% compared to the best scoring document isn't really very meaningful.  Scores are relative to the query, and the other documents in the index, so the results observed with this cutoff may vary wildly depending on the makeup of the query, as well as varying over time as the indexed data changes.

The second best result for a query may have a score an order of magnitude different from the top result, but that does not necessarily make the result irrelevant, especially with more complex queries.  Adding, removing or modifying a document could easily make results disappear from searches they had always appeared for before.

[See here](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ScoresAsPercentages), for further reading on the topic.

Comment: Yeah. The situation is kind of an odd one. My set of documents is static so changes as data is added/removed are not a concern. I'm trying to cluster the documents, seeing which ones are similar to one another and the number of similar ones may vary widely across the dataset.